# entity framework 7 introducing foreign key constraint on table may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

This question is about EF Core.

I am getting this error when I 'dotnet ef update database':

```
Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_PupilTests_Tests_TestId' on table 'PupilTests' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.
Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.
```

I understand why I get that error and I tried to remove the error by correctly setting up the DeleteBehavior but it just does not work.

So what is wrong with my fluent configuration?

**Fluent configuration:**

```
builder.Entity<Test>().HasMany<PupilTest>(x => x.PupilsTests).WithOne(p => p.Test).HasForeignKey(p => p.TestId).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);

builder.Entity<Pupil>().HasMany<PupilTest>(x => x.PupilsTests).WithOne(p => p.Pupil).HasForeignKey(p => p.PupilId).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
```

**Model**

```
public class Pupil
{
    public Pupil()
    {
        PupilsTests = new HashSet<PupilTest>();

    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ISet<PupilTest> PupilsTests { get; set; }
}


public class PupilTest
{
    public int PupilId { get; set; }
    public int TestId { get; set; }
    public decimal Scores { get; set; } 
    public Pupil Pupil { get; set; }
    public Test Test { get; set; }
}

public class Test
{
    public Test()
    {
        PupilsTests = new HashSet<PupilTest>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }        
    public ISet<PupilTest> PupilsTests { get; set; }

}
```

**Migration**

```
 public partial class Init11 : Migration
    {
        protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {
            migrationBuilder.DropForeignKey(
                name: "FK_PupilTests_Pupils_PupilId",
                table: "PupilTests");

            migrationBuilder.AddForeignKey(
                name: "FK_PupilTests_Pupils_PupilId",
                table: "PupilTests",
                column: "PupilId",
                principalTable: "Pupils",
                principalColumn: "Id",
                onDelete: ReferentialAction.Restrict);
        }

        protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {
            migrationBuilder.DropForeignKey(
                name: "FK_PupilTests_Pupils_PupilId",
                table: "PupilTests");

            migrationBuilder.AddForeignKey(
                name: "FK_PupilTests_Pupils_PupilId",
                table: "PupilTests",
                column: "PupilId",
                principalTable: "Pupils",
                principalColumn: "Id",
                onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
        }
    }
```

Comment: How looks the generated migration?

Comment: Update with migration!

Comment: May be you should have removed the previous migration first, because it's failing with the other FK (`'FK_PupilTests_Tests_TestId`) which is not part of this migration. Otherwise the fluent configuration is ok and works correctly in clean environment (i.e. a migration that creates the 3 tables and FKs)

Comment: ah that was it. Delete database + migrations folder and started from scratch. Although I did that before but my fluent was a bit different then. Thanks for testing in clean env!